# Batchscript find all lines contains text and save output

Tags: batch-file

I have a file (file.txt) containing:
**Original:**

```
== EXAMPLE1 ==
   info www.example.com H1231 2 0 19128 XXX02 == EXAMPLE
   info www.example.com H1232 2 3 19107 XXX02 == EXAMPLE
   info www.example.com H1233 3 2 19307 XXX02 == EXAMPLE
   info www.example.com H1234 0 1 19407 XXX02 == EXAMPLE
   info www.example.com H1235 0 2 19507 XXX02 == EXAMPLE
```

And this is my script

```
set "string1=abc"
set "file=file.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i "\<%string1%\>" %file%') do set "print=%%a"
echo %print% > print.txt
```

I need to get output like this

```
H1231   19128
H1232   19107
H1233   19307
H1234   19407
H1235   19507
```

Can anyone help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a corrected version of the method you had yourself attempted.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "string1=info"
Set "file=file.txt"

(For /F "Tokens=1,3,6" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "\<%string1%\>" "%file%" 2^>NUL') Do If /I "%%G" == "%string1%" Echo %%H    %%I) 1>"print.txt"
```

Comment: Nice, it works. If I wants to find the string "www.example.com". What's the change?

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Comment: Sorry, I've found a solution

Comment: I can see no way that this solution does not omit `O1231    XX102` etc. as claimed by OP on revised example data. ¯\\_(?)_/¯

Comment: This solution was written before `== EXAMPLE2 ==` was added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q76438339.txt"
set "string1=info"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 FOR /f "tokens=2,5delims= " %%g IN ("!line:*%string1%=!") DO IF "%%h" neq "" ECHO %%g %%h
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should perform that task, given the restricted **ORIGINAL** example data.

Documentation : `set /?` and `for /?` from the prompt

Comment: Almost close, this script outputs all the lines that are not searched for. Thanks